# Why written G flat instead if F sharp?

Tags: accidentals

Hi thanks in advance for answering. I’m learning a tune that is written in D major,  where Fs as written are  sharp , the arrangement in one measure goes :   G Fnat Ab Gb.

Why not just write F instead of G flat?

The piece is in D maj. F would be sharp anyhow.

Comment: It could be an error; there could be a good reason.  It's impossible to know without knowing what else is going on.  Can you name the piece or, better yet, post an image of the sheet music?

Comment: Need to see the dots, please!

Comment: My point of view: just because f sharp and g flat map to the same key on a piano is insufficient reason to replace one by the other.

Comment: @guidot that is correct, but it is also correct that sufficient reasons exist.  Whether there are any such reasons here is not yet knowable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a G♭ and an F#?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2/whats-the-difference-between-a-g-and-an-f)

Comment: Agreeing with @guidot comment #3, this could be a deliberate will from the editor in order for potential copyright infringements to be easily proven. I've seen that so many times in the 60's. Could OP also inform about the editor ?

Comment: @MC68020 enharmonic respelling is not going to provide a very convincing defense against infringement proceedings.  A legitimate theoretical reason could exist, however.  For example, if the piece temporarily tonicizes the raised fourth degree, it would be more legible to spell it as the lowered fifth degree, and the seventh of `V7/♭V` is G♭.  Or maybe it's the third of the minor chord built on the lowered second degree, or ...

Comment: This might be a portion of the D major piece that actually isn't in D major. Key signatures not reflecting the excerpt's current key is common in classical-era sonata-allegros. For more disgusting examples, there's at least one edition of Chopin's Heroic Polonaise and the sheet music of Michael Markowski's *Shadow Rituals*.

Comment: If you add an image of the piece (at least a page, not just one or two bars) this question will probably be reopened and answered accurately.